# interface extension in typescript throws error when using x

Tags: typescript

Why is this throwing an error when I extend the `Event` with another property named `x` but not when I use another name like `xy`? Could this be a bug? Here's the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLmQbwFDLJjAC2EAzmHCQA4BcyIAriQEbR4C%20eeoksiFAFkA9k3IQMWMMggAPSCAAm5NJmz5CchszYdOQA) for the playground:

```js
interface Event {
  timestamp: number
}

interface MouseEvent extends Event {
  x: number
}
```

Comment: Seems like a clash with the browser `MouseEvent`, it seems. You get the same error with both `x` and `y` as well as any existing property like `clientX` or `shiftKey`. But if you rename the interface to, say, `MouseEventz` it immediately goes away. So I guess it counts as re-defining the existing [`x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/x) and [`y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/y) properties but not sure why.

Comment: Wow that makes sense